# Too many clients already error for session table

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I have a high traffic website and use HAProxy for LoadBalancer and put my Laravel Application on 3 servers and I have done set up a separate server for Redis and Database (my database is Postgresql).
And because I used a load balancer, I migrated all sessions into the database.

Today I had a peak on my site and most of my users got the `500 internal server` error. They often get this error when their permission/authentication needs to be checked. when I checked the log file I found that there are many database exceptions in the log file which was the reason for that internal server error.

```
[2020-01-15 14:14:21] producton.ERROR: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already (SQL: select * from "sessions" where "id" = blahblahblah limit 1) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 7): SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already (SQL: select * from \"sessions\" where \"id\" = blahblahblah limit 1) at /home/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664, Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException(code: 7): SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already at /home/site/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:31, PDOException(code: 7): SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already at /home/site/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27)
```

I have searched on the internet and find some solution, some people said that I should increase `max_connections` in PostgreSQL, some article says that you should solve this problem in the application layer. but I used the Laravel framework and I don't know what should I do.

anybody can help me?

Comment: You could move your session storage to redis instead. That would free the database up for application specific operations

Comment: @PtrTon Thanks for the suggestion, is Redis stable than PostgreSQL?

Comment: It's not about stability, it's about how fast it is with reading/writing this sort of frequently accessed data.

Comment: What is your current max_connections?  What are all those connections being used for (see 'pg_stat_activity').

Comment: @jjanes the value of max_connections is 100 and when I checked the pg_stat_activity the active connections are less than 30. I couldn't see more than 30 connection

Comment: It could be the times when there are 100 are pretty much like the 30, just "more of the same", so what are the 30 doing?  Idle in transaction?

Comment: @jjanes No, those connections are alive and after each refresh, the connection will be changed. the problem is that when my site is not in the peak time and the connections are around 25~30, I got this error again.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested there are several ways to address this problem. If you want to solve this problem on the database side you can:

- Increase the max_connections parameter (this is a short term solution)
- Use a connection pool like pgpool or pgbounncer (there are others). Obviously such an architectural change needs to be tested if your application works correctly in such an environment.